# Best way to achieve listview with edittext in 2nd column in android

Tags: android, list, listview

I want to make a listview with item name in one column and edit text ( for its quantity) in 2nd column .

What would be the best way to do it , listview or table layout .

How could you achieve something like this with listview , any reference would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you go ahead using the ListView and implement a custom Adapter. In case of tableLayout you would create the entire view all at once but in the case of a ListView only the visible listItem is created and as we scroll the other listItem views are created by re-using the earlier listItem views.

For reference you may check the following link which implements a Custom List adapter having 2 textViews which you can modify with a textView and a EditText:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/183608/Android-Lists-ListActivity-and-ListView-II-Custom